# Form validation with yup - how to strip a field after validating it?

Tags: forms, vue.js, schema, yup, vee-validate

On a `vue.js` web app I'm working on I need to be able to create passwords across multiple pages. For the form validation - which `vee-validate` and `yup` are used for -, I created a composable which adds a password field with a confirmation one to a form:

```
export const usePasswordSchema = () => ({
  password: string().required("Password required").password(),
  confirmPassword: string().oneOf([ref("password")], "Passwords do not match"),
})
```

But as it is right now, the value of `confirmPassword` field gets passed to the values object - used in the `handleSubmit` handler - as well, which I would have to filter out individually for every form that processes passwords. So added `strip` to this field, which is supposed to remove the field, but unfortunately this also disabled the validation, allowing for any value to be entered.

My question is, is there a way to have a value validated and then immediately stripped from the values object, without having to strip it manually afterwards?